# I have created a table using MUI Data Grid. When i hide the columns and refresh the page the hidden columns are visible again

Tags: react-typescript, mui-x-data-grid

I have created a table using MUI Data Grid. When I hide the columns and refresh the page the hidden columns are visible again.

I want to able to maintain the state of the columns so the hidden columns shouldn't be visible on re render.I want to be able to manage and save the state of of data grid columns and filter.

```
import { MrfColumns } from "./MrfTableColumns";
import { getMrfTabledata } from "./MrfTableServices";

const MrfTable = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = React.useState<number>(20);
  const [mrfTableData, setMrfTableData] = React.useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMrfTabledata().then((resp: any) => {
      setMrfTableData(resp.data);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(ctx.mrfId);
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        px: 4,
        height: "77vh",
      }}
    >
      <DataGrid
        rows={mrfTableData}
        columns={MrfColumns}
        components={{
          Toolbar: MrfCustomToolbar,
          NoRowsOverlay: CustomeNoRowsOverlay,
          LoadingOverlay: LinearProgress,
        }}
        loading={loading}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[20, 30, 40]}
        pageSize={pageSize}
        onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
        pagination
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
      />
    </Box>
  );
};

export default MrfTable;
```